# Integrating factor mistakes when solving 1 order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

I have an ODE:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} + 3x^{2}y = x^{2}$$ .

I got the following integrating factor:

$$e^{x^3}$$

Then I multiplied both sides, but didn't come up with the right answer. It should be:

$$y = c~e^{-x^3} + \frac{1}{3}. $$

When I come up with the following:

$$y = \left(\frac{1}{3}e^{x^3} + c\right) e^{x^3}$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When I come up with the following:

y = (ex3/3 + c) ex3 , here you have to multiply both sides by exp(-x^3) but you did multiply by exp(+x^3), so rectify it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:
$$
y'(x)+3x^2 y-x^2=0\tag{1}
$$
The associated homogeneous equation
$$
y'=-3x^2 y
$$
gives you:
$$
\frac{y'}{y}=-3x^2=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\log(y)
$$
so
$$
\log (y)=-x^3,
$$
and
$$
y(x)=e^{-x^3}.
$$
The general integral for the homogeneous equation is
$$
\left\{c\,e^{-x^3},\ c\in\mathbb{R}\right\}.
$$
Now I look for a particular solution $\bar{y}$ of the original equation. If I look for a constant, like
$$
\bar{y}(x)=a,
$$
it must be $\bar{y}'(x)=0$, hence, from $(1)$:
$$
0+3ax^2-x^2=0.
$$
It follows $a=\frac{1}{3}$ and the solution:
$$
y(x)=ce^{-x^3}+\frac{1}{3},
$$
for all $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

You found the right integrating factor, allowing us to write the ODE as $$(e^{x^3} y)'=e^{x^3}x^2,$$ by multiplying both sides by $e^{x^3}.$ Integrating both sides gives $$ e^{x^3} y=\frac{e^{x^3}}{3}+c.$$ Now, just multiply both sides by $e^{-x^3},$ which gives $$y(x)=\frac{1}{3}+ce^{-x^3},$$ since $e^{-x^3}e^{x^3}=1.$ It looks like you should've multiplied both sides by $e^{-x^3}$ but did $e^{x^3}$, by mistake.

Comment: I am confused when this minus is coming from.

Comment: I'm using that $e^{-x^3}e^{x^3}=1.$ This allows us to remove the $e^{x^3}$ from the left-hand side.

Comment: Omg right! Then we get 1 in the LHS and the right solution on the RHS.

Comment: Exactly, and you're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Your LHS should read $$\frac{d}{dx}(e^{x^3}y),$$ so after integrating both sides, you have to divide by $e^{x^3}$ (i.e. multiply by $e^{-x^3}$) to obtain $y(x)$.

Comment: When did we get this minus sign from?

Comment: $x^ax^b = x^{a+b}$, so $x^{-a}x^a = x^0 = 1$. That is, the multiplicative inverse of $x^a$ is $x^{-a}$.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably forgotten to put minus sign when dividing by $e^{x^3}$.

$$e^{x^3}dy + 3x^2e^{x^3}dx = e^{x^3}x^2dx\\
d(e^{x^3}y)=\frac13d(e^{x^3})\\
e^{x^3}y=\frac13e^{x^3}+C\\
y=Ce^{-x^3}+\frac13$$

Comment: When does it come from?

Comment: $C/e^{x^3} = Ce^{-x^3}$